# stackView set constraints of custom UIView in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, uistackview

I'm trying to do a demo like tweet, and I use StackView to control layout of "nickname"、"content"、"images" and ""comments", but the layout of images has some problems, just like the photo below:

I create a custom UIView `GalleyView` and `commentsView` to represent `images` and `comments`. However, the layout of images is not right in my demo. However, `images` didn't show correctly, and `comments` are disappe. Also, `Cell` cannot calculate height correctly, and I don't know what's going wrong. Here is my code:

```swift
class WechatMomentListCell: UITableViewCell{
    
 func setup() {
        contentView.addSubview(senderAvatar)
        contentView.addSubview(stackView)
        
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.distribution = .fill
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(senderNick)
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        stackView.setCustomSpacing(10, after: senderNick)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(content)
        stackView.setCustomSpacing(10, after: content)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(images)
        stackView.setCustomSpacing(10, after: images)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(comments)
        
        senderAvatar.clipsToBounds = true;
        senderAvatar.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
        senderAvatar.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
            make.leading.top.equalTo(20)
            make.width.height.equalTo(46)
        }
        
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints{(make) in
            make.top.equalTo(20)
            make.leading.equalTo(senderAvatar.snp.trailing).offset(10)
            make.bottom.trailing.equalTo(-16)
        }
        
        senderNick.textColor = UIColor.init(red: 91, green: 106, blue: 175)
        senderNick.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)

        content.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping;
        content.numberOfLines = 0;

        //I didn't set constraints to images and comments
```

and here is my `GalleryViews` class:

```
class GalleryView: UIView {
    var imageViews: [UIImageView] = []
    
    func config(tweet: Tweet?) {
        for i in tweet?.images ?? [] {
            let flagImage = UIImageView()
            flagImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: i.url))
            self.imageViews.append(flagImage)
        }
        setup()
    }
    
    func setup() {
        if imageViews.count != 0 {
            switch imageViews.count{
            case 1:
                addSubview(imageViews[0])
                imageViews[0].snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
                    make.leading.top.equalToSuperview()
                    make.width.height.equalTo(180)
                }
            default:
                for index in 0...imageViews.count - 1 {
                    addSubview(imageViews[index])
                    imageViews[index].snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
                        make.leading.equalTo(((index)%3)*109)
                        make.top.equalTo(((index)/3)*109)
                        make.width.height.equalTo(90)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Keep your image in a separate view and your text in a separate view. then put the both views in your stack view.

Comment: Thanks, and I figured it out just an hour ago! It caused by Xcode's reminder at a `if` judgement. It is too simple so that I didn't check that place. I hide the picture when the counts is not nil, and that cause the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using stack view which holds a list of UIView, you should reset the stack view every time you use it before you start appending arranged subviews.

```swift
stackView.arrangedSubviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
```

Comment: should I reset in func prepareForReuse? And the complier shows "Value of type 'UIStackView' has no member 'forEach'"

Comment: Sorry man I forgot the arranged subviews part I have edited the answer. Now, this should work. you can do it in ```setup()```  method too.

Comment: thanks, in my case I just need to remove every image from superview.